# Function Trouble in Java Programming

Tags: java, function

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradePointAverage
{
    public static double processAverage(int []SubjectGrades,int SubjectsNumber)
    {
        double sum=0;
        double Ave=0;
        for(int i=0;i<SubjectGrades.length;i++)
        {
            sum=SubjectGrades[i]+sum;
        }
        Ave=sum/SubjectsNumber;
            return Ave;
    }
    public static int processNumericalValue(double Ave)
    {
        int Numeral;
        if(Ave>=98.0&&Ave<100.0)
        {
            Numeral=4;
        }
        else if(Ave>=90.0&&Ave<98.0)
        {
            Numeral=3;
        }
        else if(Ave>=80.0&&Ave<90.0)
        {
            Numeral=2;
        }
        else if(Ave>=75.0&&Ave<80.0)
        {
            Numeral=1;
        }
        else
        {
            Numeral=0;
        }
            return Numeral;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double Ave=0;
        Scanner peace=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many subjects do you want to enter?: ");
        int SubjectsNumber=peace.nextInt();
        int []SubjectGrades=new int [SubjectsNumber];
        String []Subjects=new String [SubjectsNumber];
        for(int i=0;i<SubjectsNumber;i++)
        {
            Subjects[i]=""; 
            System.out.print("Enter Subject No "+(i+1)+": ");
            Subjects[i]=peace.next();
        }   
            for(int i=0;i<Subjects.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("What is your grade in "+Subjects[i]+": ");
                SubjectGrades[i]=peace.nextInt();
            }
        int Numeral;
        double x=processAverage(SubjectGrades,SubjectsNumber);
        System.out.println(x);
        int y=processNumericalValue(Ave);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Good Evening!. Well this is my second time to ask here. If i remember last March 10 i posted a trouble in array. This time what I want to know is why my function don't return the desired answer. I think my second function does not read the Ave that's why the answer in Numeral is 0. It doesn't change even if Ave=96 or any number. Can you help me how to let my function processNumericalValue read the Ave in my first function processAverage. Hoping to be in your guidance again guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
double x=processAverage(SubjectGrades,SubjectsNumber);
```

use:

```
Ave =processAverage(SubjectGrades,SubjectsNumber);
```

Reason you get 0 as output, is you are calling `int y=processNumericalValue(Ave);` with Ave as input and you never modify the value of Ave and you pass on the value as 0 (to what you initialized initially in the main method).

Comment: What about this: `Ave=sum/SubjectsNumber;`

Comment: you said he never modifies ave but he does.

Comment: @SMA never mind I thought you meant he never modifies it in the processAverage(). All good :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
    double x = processAverage(SubjectGrades,SubjectsNumber);
    System.out.println(x);
    int y = processNumericalValue(Ave);
```

You need to pass x not Ave because x has the value of the average not Ave:

```
int y = processNumericalValue(x);
```

Some code consolidation.

```
 for(int i=0;i<SubjectsNumber;i++)
    {
        Subjects[i]=""; 
        System.out.print("Enter Subject No "+(i+1)+": ");
        Subjects[i]=peace.next();
    }   
        for(int i=0;i<Subjects.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("What is your grade in "+Subjects[i]+": ");
            SubjectGrades[i]=peace.nextInt();
        }
```

You can reduce this code to:

```
for(int i=0;i<SubjectsNumber;i++) {
    Subjects[i]=""; 
    System.out.print("Enter Subject No "+(i+1)+": ");
    Subjects[i]=peace.next();
    System.out.println("What is your grade in "+Subjects[i]+": ");
    SubjectGrades[i]=peace.nextInt();
}
```

Also this:

```
public static double processAverage(int[] grades)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double ave = 0; // try to use lowercase for variable names
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        sum += grades[i];
    }
    ave = sum/grades.length;
    return ave;
}
```

Function call:

```
double x = processAverage(SubjectGrades);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradePointAverage
{
    public static double processAverage(int []SubjectGrades,int SubjectsNumber)
    {
        double sum=0;
        double Ave=0;
        for(int i=0;i<SubjectGrades.length;i++)
        {
            sum=SubjectGrades[i]+sum;
        }
            Ave=sum/SubjectsNumber;
            return Ave;
    }
    public static int processNumericalValue(double Ave)
    {
        int Numeral;
        if(Ave>=98.0&&Ave<100.0)
        {
            Numeral=4;
        }
        else if(Ave>=90.0&&Ave<98.0)
        {
            Numeral=3;
        }
        else if(Ave>=80.0&&Ave<90.0)
        {
            Numeral=2;
        }
        else if(Ave>=75.0&&Ave<80.0)
        {
            Numeral=1;
        }
        else
        {
            Numeral=0;
        }
            return Numeral;
    }
    public static void processLetterGrade(int Numeral)
    {
        if(Numeral==4)
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations!");
        }
        else if(Numeral==3)
        {
            System.out.println("Your Letter Grade is B!");
        }
        else if(Numeral==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Your Letter Grade is C!");
        }
        else if(Numeral==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Your Letter Grade is D!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You Failed!");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double Ave=0;
        Scanner peace=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many subjects do you want to enter?: ");
        int SubjectsNumber=peace.nextInt();
        int []SubjectGrades=new int [SubjectsNumber];
        String []Subjects=new String [SubjectsNumber];
        for(int i=0;i<SubjectsNumber;i++)
        {
            Subjects[i]=""; 
            System.out.print("Enter Subject No "+(i+1)+": ");
            Subjects[i]=peace.next();
            System.out.println("What is your grade in "+Subjects[i]+": ");
            SubjectGrades[i]=peace.nextInt();
        }
            int Numeral;
            Ave=processAverage(SubjectGrades,SubjectsNumber);
            System.out.println("Your General Average is: "+Ave);
            Numeral=processNumericalValue(Ave);
            System.out.println("Numerical Value is: "+Numeral);
            processLetterGrade(Numeral);
    }
}
```